# "Ill-formed clause" issue, mit-scheme

Tags: scheme, lisp

Trying some Lisp, using mit-scheme.

```
(define (inv curstate x y)
  ((cond (= y 1) curstate)
   (cond (even? y)
         (inv (square curstate) x (/ y 2)))
   (else 
    (inv (* x curstate) x (- y 1)))))
```

An interpreter error:

> Ill-formed clause: curstate

Another version use linear recursion method, so there's a similar error with it.
What to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your syntax for `cond` is wrong. Here's the same code with a corrected syntax:

```
(define (inv curstate x y)
  (cond ((= y 1) curstate)
        ((even? y)
         (inv (square curstate) x (/ y 2)))
        (else
         (inv (* x curstate) x (- y 1)))))
```